# Propagación de aferTextChangedListener en Android

Tags: java, android

Tengo dos EditText en una activity y quiero que, al cambiar el valor de uno, se actualice el valor del otro, y viceversa.

Lo he intentado con `afterTextChangedListener` pero al cambiar uno entran en un bucle infinito. Creo que la solución es evitar la propagación, pero desconozco cómo hacerlo.

Este es el código de la Activity:

```
private TextView coin;
private EditText editTextCoin, editTextEuros;
private float value;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.conversor);

    setUpVars();
    initializeUI();
    setUpButtons();
    onChangeListeners();

    priceCoin();
}

private void initializeUI() {
    coin.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("nameCoin"));
}

private void setUpVars() {;
    coin = findViewById(R.id.nom_moneda_1);
    editTextCoin = findViewById(R.id.valor_moneda_1);
    editTextEuros = findViewById(R.id.valor_moneda_2);
}

private void setUpButtons() {

}

private void onChangeListeners() {
    editTextCoin.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!editTextCoin.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                editTextEuros.setText(String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(editTextCoin.getText().toString()) * value));
            } else {
                editTextCoin.setText(String.valueOf(1.0));
                editTextEuros.setText(String.valueOf(1 * value));
            }

            //Toast.makeText(Conversor.this, editTextCoin.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    editTextEuros.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!editTextEuros.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                editTextCoin.setText(String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(editTextEuros.getText().toString()) / value));
            } else {
                editTextEuros.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                editTextCoin.setText(String.valueOf(value / value));
            }
        }
    });
}

// Petició a l'api
@Override
public void processFinish(String output) {
    JSONObject json = null;

    try {
        Log.d("response_", output);
        json = new JSONObject(output);
        if (json.has("Response")) {
            if (json.getString("Response").equals("Error")){
                Toast.makeText(this, json.getString("Message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, json.getString("EUR"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(this, json.getString("EUR"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            value = Float.parseFloat(json.getString("EUR"));
            editTextCoin.setText(String.valueOf(1.0));
            editTextEuros.setText(String.valueOf(1 * value));
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void priceCoin(){
    CoinsJson coinPrice = new CoinsJson(this);
    coinPrice.delegate = this;

    String url = Global.base_url.concat(Global.url_price).replace("coinName", getIntent().getStringExtra("coin"));
    coinPrice.execute(url);
    Log.d("url_", url);
}
// Fi petició a l'api
```

Comment: Muestra el código que tiene.

Comment: Este es el código de la Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sincronizar dos [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) con [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) es muy fácil.

Antes que nada implementa [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) en tu [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) no se de que tipo de Activity estas heredando solo agrega implements al final como por ejemplo.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher { 
  // Tu código tal como está
}
```

En el método `setUpVars()` agrega los listeners del [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) a tus [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html):

```
    private void setUpVars() {
    // Tu codigo tal como está

        editTextCoin.addTextChangedListener(this);
        editTextEuro.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        if(editable.hashCode() == editTextCoin.getEditableText().hashCode() && editTextCoin.hasFocus()){
            editTextEuro.setText(editable.toString());
        }
        else if(editable.hashCode() == editTextEuro.getEditableText().hashCode() && editTextEuro.hasFocus())
        {
            editTextCoin.setText(editable.toString());
        }
    }
```

La lógica es la siguiente:

- Si el [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) en el que estás escribiendo (comparando el hashCode del `Editable` ya que no recibe un `View`) tiene el Focus, manda el Texto al otro `EditText` y viceversa. Asi te aseguras que cuando se llame `AfterTextChanged` nuevamente. Como el que está activo es el emisor, cuando el receptor vea que no tiene el Focus, evitará propagar el listener (hacer setText).

Cualquier inquietud me dejas saber.

Comment: Funciona a la perfección gracias.