# Textwatcher entre edittext cruzados

Tags: android-studio, edittext

estoy tratando de hacer una calculadora de IGV, en Android Studio, con algunas características adicionales y cuento con varios EditText. Necesito que al modificar cualquiera de ellos, se cambie el valor de los otros.

Con el Textwatcher logro esto pero Unidireccionalmente. Es decir, Si tengo 3 EditTexts llamados: Subtotal, Igv y Total y se realiza lo siguiente:
1.- Escribo 100 en "Total", esto causa que "subtotal" sea igual a 84.75 y que "IGV" sea 15.25. Pero si lleno "Subtotal" con 84.75 se me cuelga debido a que, me imagino yo, se crea un circulo vicioso ya que "Subtotal" modificaría "Total", pero este a su vez quiere modificar el primero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
final EditText campoVentas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total_venta);
    final EditText campoSubtotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subtotal_venta);
    final EditText campogananciaporc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ganancia_porc);
    TextWatcher generalTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (campoVentas.getText().hashCode() == editable.hashCode()) {
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Campo Ventas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();
                if(null == editable || editable.length() == 0){

                    EditText subtotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subtotal_venta);
                    EditText igv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.igv_venta);
                    subtotal.setText("");
                    igv.setText("");
                }
                else {

                    EditText subtotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subtotal_venta);
                    EditText igv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.igv_venta);
                    Float num2 = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(editable));
                    double operacion = num2 / 1.18;
                    double resta = num2 - operacion;
                    String valor = String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f",operacion));
                    String valor2 = String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f",resta));
                    subtotal.setText(valor);
                    igv.setText(valor2);


                }
            } else if (campoSubtotal.getText().hashCode() == editable.hashCode()) {
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Campo subtotal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();
                if(null == editable || editable.length() == 0){

                    EditText total = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total_venta);
                    EditText igv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.igv_venta);
                    //total.setText("");
                    igv.setText("");
                }
                else {

                    EditText total = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total_venta);
                    EditText igv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.igv_venta);
                    final Float num2 = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(editable));
                    double operacion = num2 * 0.18;
                    double suma = num2 + operacion;
                    String valor = String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f",operacion));
                    String valor2 = String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f",suma));
                    igv.setText(valor);
                    //total.setText(valor2); //ES ACÁ DONDE FALLA
                }
```

A ver si me pueden echar una manito. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Para ello debes definir bien tu lógica. Para evitar propagar el evento a un ciclo infinito revisa [ESTA RESPUESTA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/138077/38154) que hice hace un tiempo, es entendible, ya definirías tu lógica como creas.